# S&P 500 List python script crashes

Tags: python, finance

So I have been following a youtube tutorial on Python finance and since Yahoo has now closed its doors to the financial market, it has caused a few dwelling problems.

I run this code

```
    import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt 
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf


def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org       /wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(ticker, f)

            print(tickers)

    return tickers

# save_sp500_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):

    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2017, 8, 24)

    for ticker in tickers:
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

    get_data_from_yahoo()
```

and it crashes with a few erros, not just one. The first error is that I should override pandas data reader.

```
DeprecationWarning: 
Auto-overriding of pandas_datareader's get_data_yahoo() is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
Use pdr_override() to explicitly override it.
DeprecationWarning)
```

How do I override it? I really don't know how to, I am new to Python - sorry for being a noob.

Then we have this:

```
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\Python finance\SP500_List.py", line 36, in get_data_from_yahoo
    tickers = pickle.load(f)
```

I really dont understand why this happens, because I have checked my code with the Youtuber and they match. So some pointer would be appriciated.

Finally, I have this error:

```
  EOFError: Ran out of input
```

which I also don't know what it means.

To add to that, I have installed the 'fix_yahoo_finance' package and tried that with the new code as well and it still does not work.

Any help is appriciated. Thanks :)

Full error list:

```
C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fix_yahoo_finance\__init__.py:43: DeprecationWarning: 
    Auto-overriding of pandas_datareader's get_data_yahoo() is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
    Use pdr_override() to explicitly override it.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\Python finance\SP500_List.py", line 51, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\Python finance\SP500_List.py", line 36, in get_data_from_yahoo
    tickers = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
[Finished in 3.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\Python finance\SP500_List.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\Python finance]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.8.5.35155\bin\Firefox_Extension\{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.8.5.35155\ucrt]
```

Comment: Deprecation warnings are not errors really. Your code will still run, but if you upgrade the library in the future, it might break.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not sure if it runs. A file called sp500tickers.pickle was made in the directory but I still think more should've happened.

Comment: Yes, well, **you are getting errors**, but the deprecation warning isn't one of them. But you haven't properly posted the errors. Provide the *full error message including the stack trace*. Although, I suspect it is one error, and it is being caused by trying to unpickle an empty file.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga here is the full error message(s). Actually, it's too long so I will add it to the end of the question.

Comment: What is `df` in `df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))`? When I run the code I get `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`.

Comment: @ands so to explain this we must go to the line before that. The if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)): is checking to see if a file exists. If it doesn't the df is a variable that reads using the data reader whatever the start, end and the location of the data. More on this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baCAFPHb1o4  skip to 6:20 and it should explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  have two mistakes in your code:

1. In line 22 in function `save_sp500_tickers()`, instead of this:

   ```
   with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
       pickle.dump(ticker, f)
   ```

   it should be:

   ```
   with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
       pickle.dump(tickers, f)
   ```

   So it is tickers instead of ticker
2. In line 47 in function `get_data_from_yahoo()`, instead of this:

   ```
   if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
       data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
       df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
       data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
       data.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
   ```

   You need to use `data` instead of `df` (in video was used `df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)` which you change in `data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)` but you forgot to change `df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))` to `data.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))`)

Comment: so I made the changes and they worked! Thanks for your help. It ran perfectly. However, when I change the location of the get_data_from_yahoo() it produces the same errors. But if I indent it under the 'ticker' loop it compiles. But if it is all the way to the left it gives errors. Is this a Python indentation being tough or is there still a problem?

Comment: I didnt get where do you put get_data_yahoo() when you change its location, but yes [indentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments) is very important in python, if code is not indented then it would not be inside the loop.

Comment: Oh right okay. The get_data_from_yahoo() actually wasn't in the loop. Once I put it in the loop, that's when it worked. Thanks for your help