# python - finance - EOF Error - ran out of input

Tags: python, finance

I'm just writing code from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baCAFPHb1o4) in YouTube and I'm stumped on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/john/pycharm_coding/stock_investing_using_AI/stock investing/do 
now/scripts/finance.py", line 49, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "C:/Users/john/pycharm_coding/stock_investing_using_AI/stock investing/do now/scripts/finance.py", line 31, in get_data_from_yahoo
tickers = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I checked the code and everything is the same(unless you count the variable names), so I'm really puzzled.

Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests
from datetime import date


link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baCAFPHb1o4'
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
        print(tickers)
    return tickers
# save_sp500_tickers()
def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_data'):
        os.makedirs('stock_data')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = date.today()

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)

        if not os.path.exists('stock_data/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            print('Scraping data from' + ticker + '...')
            data = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            data.to_csv('stock_data/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
            print('Done.')
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

get_data_from_yahoo()
```

I searched the web but I found only one result that matched my case, but it was a not-so-helpful one, and just in case you want to know what it is, here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889883/sp-500-list-python-script-crashes).

At first, I tried copying the code and pasting the code from that one and then solving it with the answers below, but then it just went 'Process finished with exit code 0', and got no output when there was supposed to be lots. I then figured out that I didn't call it and then unindented the last line, but then the EOFError came again.

Comment: The pickle file may be empty. Does the pickle file have zero size?

Comment: @ankur oh yeah it is empty! How come it's empty? I wrote the code that fills it with stuff! might be that I didn't run that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code in my environment.
The cause is the specification of the data reader, 'yahoo' is not needed. However, I could not get all the issues. There are some cases where the data does not exist for some stocks, so you need to have the corresponding code.

```
#data = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
data = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
```

Comment: uh, and why are some data that are missing or do not exist?

Comment: I think it might be a delisting or a company merger.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I actually found out that the pickle file was empty because I forgot to run the code that fills the file with stuff before running get_data_from_yahoo, but if you didn't tell me to remove 'yahoo', it would give me a '
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: yahoo' error.

Comment: If you get a date error, it's probably this line, so try changing it to `dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`.